# Parse a sequence list for a specific item and map it to its key in yaml using ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

Need to write a ruby script that will parse a yaml file based on an argument given to the script.

Below is an example of something similar to what the yaml file looks like:

```
server01:
  - mail
  - dhcp
  - dns 
server02:
  - mail
  - dhcp
```

Would like to be able to run the script like so, ./test.rb -s mail

and have it return a list of server(s) that have mail in their sequence list

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `'mail'` with the right argument. I'm guessing something like `ARGV[1]`?

```
require 'yaml'
h = YAML.load_file('config.yaml')
h.select { |k, v| v.include?('mail') }.keys
# => should return ["server01","server02"]
```

Comment: I get undefined method keys for Array

Comment: @TonyD `.map(&:first)` instead of `keys` should solve this. You could also do `collect{|k,v| k if v.include('mail)}.compact`

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks! That does it! Now my next step is to check and see if what the user inputs exists and then exit or move on to what I originally asked. Thanks!

Comment: About the "undefined method keys" error, you must be using a very old Ruby version (1.8). From 1.9 on, the `select` method returns a hash, not an array. engineersmnsky's comment will work in 1.8.x.

Comment: @Teoulas if the OP is using OSX and has a version less than 10.9 (Mavericks) then the native ruby is 1.8.7. This would be my assumption thus why I supplied backwards compatible solutions which will work in all versions but your answer is definitely more concise and idiomatic ruby code for all versions 1.9+

Comment: @engineersmnky good point! It didn't cross my mind that someone would be using such an old Ruby version, let alone one that has reached end-of-life 3 years ago.